# Can't access my ASP.NET Core Web API when running it from the publish dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a very simple ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API. When I run it using Visual Studio or Rider, I can access it via the swagger page.

I want to publish my API, so I went and used:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish
```

to create the release DLL's files.

When I run `dotnet MyWebApp.dll` it tells me that the application is now listening to http://0.0.0.0:10001 just like it does when I run it from the the IDE. However now if I want to access my swagger page, it tells me that the page was not found and returns me 404.

This is how I configured my WebHost:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    await host.RunAsync();
}

private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .ConfigureKestrel((_, options) =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 10001, listenOptions => { listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1; });
            })
            .UseWebRoot("")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I also tried to run it via the `.exe` file, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. My application was not properly configured for the Hosting Environment: Production.
I set my Environment to Development with:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Afterwards everything works fine. I spent so much time on this and it didn't cross my mind to check the environment my application was running using the dotnet command.